# CSS Gradients stopping then repeating

Tags: html, css

I want to make my background on my site a gradient. This is because I am just starting out making sites, and I just want to learn how CSS works and what not.

Here is my code:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

I do NOT want the gradient to stop then repeat from white. I want the gradient to change depending on the current media's size.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, it appears to work fine in Chrome. Any particular web browser you're having a problem with?

Comment: I am using Chrome. The Gradient stops halfway down the page then repeats from the top. The gradient is set to a fixed size, I would like it to resize. I would post a picture of my site, but I do not want to be made fun of.

Comment: Hey, we all gotta start somewhere. Anyway, looks like the problem might be something in a different part of your HTML/CSS, answers below might help. Using just what you gave me, I put together this: http://jsfiddle.net/jcolicchio/LFN3R/ and it appears to work just fine...

Comment: Here is what I have now. I need some tips on layout design.
http://i.imgur.com/35ij8.png

Comment: As the top answer suggested, you need to set html and body's height to 100%. And then set the body's background-image to those things as you have right now. As for your layout, what are you trying to display in that rectangle? What's an example of a finished product?

Comment: I don't really have an example for a finished product. It is just a test platform for me to learn design. I just wish I could figure things out in HTML and CSS as I can in Java.

Comment: Ahh, it'll take a while, just keep practicing. I recommend sites like jsfiddle.net and thecodeplayer.com for learning and practicing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to do, apply height:100%  to html and body. If your site will be on mobile devices you will need to add

background-attachment: fixed to the body as well.

```
  html{
 height: 100%;
 }
 body{
 height: 100%;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */}
```

Comment: Thank you. Although it seems like an odd fix.

Answer (score 2):

Set `height` and `width` of html and body to 100%, and these options for the background:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EAmau)

If you don't the gradient will repeat when your scroll past the height of the browser.